# SVN doesn't ignore a nested directory

Tags: svn

For some reason `svn` doesn't ignore a folder, even though I told it to.

```
$ svn rm --keep-local www/tmp
$ svn st        
?       www/tmp
$ cat .svnignore 
www/tmp
```

Why doesn't svn properly ignore the `www/tmp` folder?

Answer (score 2):

svn doesn't use a `.svnignore` file. You have to set the [`svn:ignore`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html) property on the directory you are using.

You can set the property using the file by using the following command:

```
svn propset svn:ignore -F .svnignore .
```

...but note that this sets the property from the current content of the file; changes to the file are not automatically picked up.

Comment: what is the value of the 'svn:ignore' property?  'svn propget svn:ignore`